# Relocate based on first none zero value with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to order my columns based on the string name and first none zero value in each column.

assuming I have the following data:

```
col1_A  col2_A col1_B col2_B 
   0       0      0      0   
   0       2      0      4 
   3       12     1      1
```

I need to order them in a way that columns with names including '_A' are place before '_B' and then the column with the first none zero value comes first. The expected out put will be:

```
col2_A  col1_A col1_B col2_B 
   0       0      0      0   
   2       0      4      0 
   12      3      1      1
```

Here is the sample data for replicating.

```
df = data.frame('col1_A'=c(0,0,3),'col2_A'=c(0,2,12),'col1_B'=c(0,0,1),'col2_B'=c(0,4,1))
```

UPDATE:

Colnames are just examples, and the only the last character is important! hence I changed them to this now to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way using `split.default` -

```
purrr::map_dfc(split.default(df, sub('.*_', '', names(df))), function(x) {
  x[order(sapply(x, function(x) match(TRUE, x !=0)))]
})

#  col2_A col1_A col2_B col1_B
#1      0      0      0      0
#2      2      0      4      0
#3     12      3      1      1
```

`sub` keeps only the important last character in the output. We split the data accordingly.

```
sub('.*_', '', names(df))
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "B"
```

For each group (`A` and `B`) we extract the position of first non zero value (`match(TRUE, x!= 0)`) and use `order` to rearrange the dataframe. `map_dfc` is used to combine the list of dataframes in one combined dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame('col1_A'=c(0,0,3),'col2_A'=c(0,2,12),'col3_B'=c(0,0,1),'col4_B'=c(0,4,1))


df %>% 
  imap_chr(~ str_c(str_extract(.y, "\\w$"),
                   which(.x != 0)[1])) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  {df[.$name]}
#>   col2_A col1_A col4_B col3_B
#> 1      0      0      0      0
#> 2      2      0      4      0
#> 3     12      3      1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @shs, Thats amazing. Small fix that it needs is that, col4_B should also be placed befor col3_B.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood the question as sorting by the first occuring non-zero value, I changed it

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly for the dummy dataset. However I am not an expert with str_extract so have a little bit challenge to adopt it to my actual dataset. where instead of "_A" and "_B" I have "_cost" and "_output" and before "_" is not sorted by numbers it's random characters. How can I str_extract based on ending in "_cost" or "_output"?